# site.addsitedir doesn't add egg to sys.path

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have a python module packaged by distutils into a zipped egg installed in a custom prefix. If I set PYTHONPATH to contain that prefix's site-packages directory, the egg is added to sys.path and the module can be imported. If I instead from within the script run site.addsitedir with the prefix's site-packages directory, however, the egg is not added to sys.path and the module import fails. In both cases, the module's site-packages directory ends up in sys.path.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there any way to tell Python to process the .pth files in a given directory without setting an env var?

Comment: what is in .pth file? Does it work if you manually add the egg to sys.path? Are Python versions that created and use the egg the same?

Comment: .pth file: import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./webcharon-0.1-py2.7.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)

Comment: Python versions are the same. Same binary, in fact.

Comment: Whoops, in the .pth file there's a newline before './webcharon...' and after '.egg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I set PYTHONPATH to contain that prefix's site-packages directory, the egg is added to sys.path and the module can be imported.

Adding some directory to `PYTHONPATH` doesn't trigger processing of `.pth`-files in it. Therefore your zipped egg won't be in `sys.path`. You can import a module from the egg only if the egg itself is in `sys.path` (parent directory is not enough).

> If I instead from within the script run site.addsitedir with the prefix's site-packages directory, however, the egg is not added to sys.path and the module import fails.

`site.addsitedir()` triggers processing of `.pth`-files if the directory hasn't been seen yet so it should work.

The behavior you described is the opposite of what should happen.

As a workaround you could add the egg to `sys.path` manually: `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/the.egg')`

Comment: Workaround worked. Not sure what's going on, couldn't reproduce on another machine.